# Pip install local python project and automatically install local subprojects

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to install a local python project I am working on with:

`pip install -e .`

I am trying to use automatic discovery detailed here: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#automatic-discovery

My code is laid out as described in the link as the "ad-hoc" layout

```
project_root_directory
├── pyproject.toml  # AND/OR setup.cfg, setup.py
├── ...
└── mypkg/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── ...
    ├── module.py
    ├── subpkg1/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── module1.py
    └── subpkg2/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── ...
        └── module2.py
```

My top level setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup,find_packages

setup(
    name = "Code", #must match the actual folder name.  
    author = "Me",
    author_email = "Me",
    description = ("Code"),
    packages=find_packages(where='mypkg'),
    python_requires='>=3.6',     
    
)
```

A few of my subdirectories that I do not wish to have as part of the package I have not put a  `__init__.py` in.

If I do not specify the packages line, or leave the "where" argument empty, the package is built successfully and can be imported, but has nothing inside it aside from the default package functions.  If I leave it as it is in the code above, it gives the following error:

`error: package directory 'subpkg1' does not exist`

The subpackage directory that is causing the error does exist in the correct location, has its own `__init__.py`, and is not even the first file or folder alphabetically in the directory.

Does anyone know what might be happening?  I would like to run a single top level call to pip to install the package and have all subpackages beneath it install as subpackages that I could dot-index to access.

Comment: `find_packages` also has an `exclude` parameter: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#finding-simple-packages -- It seems like you do not need the `where` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `package_dir={"","mypkg"}` fixed the problem and now it is automatically finding the modules.  Interestingly, it appears unable to tab-autocomplete still but can be indexed by `from mypkg.subpkg1 import module1`